# Simplexml issue.. Having a tough time trying to access this data

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to access these elements in the simplexml object with the structure below.

I'm having a hell of a time trying to get the values in this xml block:

```
<result name="doclist" numFound="9" start="0">
    <doc>
        <str name="merchant_name_url_title">accuscore</str>
        <str name="end_date_time"/>
        <str name="category">betting & gaming</str>
        <str name="merchant_name">Accuscore</str>
        <str name="link_type">Text Link</str>
    </doc>
</result>
```

I'm trying to get the value for "numFound" and the all the "doc/str"  data for each record.

### Below, is the full structure.  I'm just showing 2 "doc" elements, but there could be thousands.

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">5</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="indent">true</str>
            <str name="start">0</str>
            <str name="q">*:*</str>
            <str name="rows">2</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="grouped">
        <lst name="merchant_name">
            <int name="matches">5143</int>
            <arr name="groups">
                <lst>
                    <str name="groupValue">accuscor</str>
                    <result name="doclist" numFound="9" start="0">
                        <doc>
                            <str name="merchant_name_url_title">accuscore</str>
                            <str name="end_date_time"/>
                            <str name="category">betting & gaming</str>
                            <str name="merchant_name">Accuscore</str>
                            <str name="link_type">Text Link</str>
                        </doc>
                    </result>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="groupValue">acdse</str>
                    <result name="doclist" numFound="3" start="0">
                        <doc>
                            <str name="merchant_name_url_title">acdsee</str>
                            <str name="end_date_time"/>
                            <str name="category">computer hardware & software</str>
                            <str name="merchant_name">ACDSee</str>
                            <str name="link_type">Text Link</str>
                        </doc>
                    </result>
                </lst>
            </arr>
        </lst>
    </lst>
```

Been banging my head against the wall for hours and decided to ask for some help here!

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The XML you've pasted is invalid, not just because you've missed off the `</response>`, but because there are unescaped `&` signs in there, which should be `&amp;`.

I would also say it's clearly been written by someone who doesn't understand XML, because the element names (`str`, `arr`, `lst`, etc) seem to be defining nothing but the type of data.

However, assuming you fix that and load it into a SimpleXML object called `$sx`, you could use an XPath expression to find all the `result` elements, and proceed from there:

```
foreach ( $sx->xpath('//lst[@name="grouped"]//result') as $result )
{
        echo 'Begin Result; numFound: ' . (string)$result['numFound'] . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ( $result->doc as $doc )
        {
                echo 'Begin doc:' . PHP_EOL;
                foreach ( $doc->str as $str )
                {
                        echo (string)$str['name'] . ': ' . (string)$str . PHP_EOL;
                }
                echo 'End doc' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo 'End result' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  I missed the </response> when pasting.  Don't know what to say about the element names.  This comes out of Apache Solr's grouping reponse like that.  I have no control of the element names.

Comment: Yes, my comment on the XML structure was along the lines of "you have my pity having to deal with such ugly XML".